# Can't find the link to my Cognito form that I can email

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to send a link to my form by email to the respondents, but am not sure what link to use.

I only see the HTML code to embed into the website and I don't want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I am on the Cognito Forms Team,

Based on your username I believe you must be organization "myown".

It appears one of our security systems flagged a warning based on an attribute on your forms or account, therefore direct links were disabled. 
 I have reviewed your forms and account information and everything looks fine.
I have removed the security flag so you should see a link in the same area as the embedding code.

If you are still having problems please create a bug report [*here*](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) so we can investigate further.